# Manipulating jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am not sure what is the difference between `mDataProp` & `fnRender`. In the first case we are declaring the property as it is but in the second case we write like

```
oObj.aData['prop2'] .
```

I have two questions here .

1. Based on the value of prop1 I want to modify the value of prop2, e.g if prop1 is 1 in first column, then only prop2 should display its value in 2nd column, otherwise it should show blank.
2. Can we enable/disable the prop2 column in dataTable, based on prop1's value.

   ```
   {
      "mDataProp": "prop1",
      "bSortable": true,
      "sClass": "prop1Class"
   },
   {  "mDataProp": "prop2",
      "fnRender": function (oObj) { return oObj.aData['prop2'] ;},
      "bSortable": true,
      "sClass": "prop2Class"
   },
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mDataProp defines what data you are trying to use.

fnRender is where you assign a custom function to render the data in a different way than the default. Your example just returns the data as it is.

BTW, both are deprecated.

For the other question, maybe you can use the fnRender or mRender.
Add a custom function to display the second column either with value or blank.

Something like this...

```
"fnRender": function (oObj) { return fnXYZ(oObj, 'prop1', 'prop2') ;}

...

function fnXYZ(oObj, col1, col2) {
    if (oObj.aData[col1] == 1) {
        return oObject.aData[col2];
    }
    return "";
}
```